# Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'user_id' cannot be null while importing excel file with multiple sheet. Am Using "Laravel Excel" package

Tags: excel, laravel

I am trying to import excel file with multiple sheet... so far my normal import class works fine but when i came to importing multiple sheets i can't store the **user_id**

Here is my code

```
class FirstSheetImport implements ToCollection
{

    public function create(Request $user_id)
    {
        $user_id = Auth::user()->id;
        $this->user_id = $user_id;
    }
    public function collection(Collection $rows)
    {
        foreach ($rows as $row) {
            Medicine::create([
                'name'     => $row[0] ?? "",
                'dosage_form' => $row[1] ?? "",
                'dosage_strength' => $row[2] ?? "",
                'product_date' => $row[3] ?? "",
                'expire_date' => $row[4] ?? "",
                'unit' => $row[5] ?? "",
                'serial_no' => $row[6] ?? "",
                'user_id' => $this->user_id,
            ]);
        }
    }
}
```

and this is my normal import class

```
class MedicineImport implements ToModel, WithMultipleSheets
{
    public function sheets(): array
    {
        return [
            new FirstSheetImport()
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @param array $row
     *
     * @return User|null
     */
    public function __construct($user_id){

        $this->user_id = $user_id;
    }
    public function model(array $row)
    {
        // var_dump($row);
        // die();
        return new Medicine([
            'name'     => $row[0] ?? "",
            'dosage_form' => $row[1] ?? "",
            'dosage_strength' => $row[2] ?? "",
            'product_date' => $row[3] ?? "",
            'expire_date' => $row[4] ?? "",
            'unit' => $row[5] ?? "",
            'serial_no' => $row[6] ?? "",
            'user_id' => $this->user_id,

        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: in what context is this import running?

Comment: the users are importing their item through an excel file

Comment: why not pass the `user_id` to the constructor of the importer like you are doing to the other one since you are creating the instance yourself anyway

Comment: yeah i have try that too, and it was showing this...

Too few arguments to function App\Imports\FirstSheetImport::__construct(), 0

Comment: i have try it again with constructor and this happens...
Expected 1 arguments. Found 0.

Comment: are you passing the `id` to it when you are creating a new instance of that class in the `sheets` method?

Comment: on my normal importing class yeah
here is the code in my controller that show am passing the id
Excel::import(new MedicineImport(Auth::user()->id), request()->file('select_file'));

Comment: you need to pass it into the other class when you create the new instance of it in the `sheets` method

Comment: and how can i do that?

Comment: give me a hint.

Answer (score 1):

I got it

in my multiple import class...

```
 public function __construct($user_id)
{
    $this->user_id = $user_id;
}
public function collection(Collection $rows)
{
    $this->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        Medicine::create([
            'name'     => $row[0] ?? "",
            'dosage_form' => $row[1] ?? "",
            'dosage_strength' => $row[2] ?? "",
            'product_date' => $row[3] ?? "",
            'expire_date' => $row[4] ?? "",
            'unit' => $row[5] ?? "",
            'serial_no' => $row[6] ?? "",
            'user_id' => $this->user_id,
        ]);
    }
```

and in my new instance...

```
public function sheets(): array
{
    return [
        0 => new FirstSheetImport($this->user_id)

    ];
}
```